# Special characters in strings in Android are all turned into �

Tags: java, android, string, encoding

I'm trying to assign a String variable in my object to a value, which may contain danish letters, including æ, ø, and å. I'm trying to pass this to a server I have running, but it seems as though that all those characters are turned into � as soon as I assign them to a string, thus "Hællø Wærld" is turned into "H�ll� W�rld". Is the character encoding defaulted to something that cannot handle these characters in Android?

Code that uploads the string:

```
            url = new URL(restUrl);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();

            // TODO might have to change this to other charset to preserve æ ø å
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String test = getQuery(postParams);
            Log.d("Parametere", test);
            writer.write(test);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();

            responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
```

Where getQuery is:

```
    private String getQuery(ArrayList<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Server code that processes the string:

```
    public function createBookingReservation(BookingReservation $bookingReservation) {
    $date =                     $bookingReservation->getDate();
    $occasion =                 $bookingReservation->getOccasion();
    $guestId =                  $bookingReservation->getGuestId();
    $welcomeDrink =             $bookingReservation->getWelcomeDrink();
    $starters =                 $bookingReservation->getStarters();
    $mainCourse =               $bookingReservation->getMainCourse();
    $dessert =                  $bookingReservation->getDessert();
    $accessories =              $bookingReservation->getAccessories();
    $midnightSnack =            $bookingReservation->getMidnightSnack();
    $wine =                     $bookingReservation->getWine();
    $dessertWine =              $bookingReservation->getDessertWine();
    $cognacAndLiqueur =         $bookingReservation->getCognacAndLiqueur();
    $bar =                      $bookingReservation->getBar();
    $beerAndWater =             $bookingReservation->getBeerAndWater();
    $coffee =                   $bookingReservation->getCoffee();
    $tableArrangements =        $bookingReservation->getTableArrangements();
    $tableclothsColor =         $bookingReservation->getTableclothsColor();
    $candleColor =              $bookingReservation->getCandleColor();
    $tablePlan =                $bookingReservation->getTablePlan();
    $napkinColor =              $bookingReservation->getNapkinColor();
    $flowers =                  $bookingReservation->getFlowers();
    $musicEntertainment =       $bookingReservation->getMusicEntertainment();
    $notes =                    $bookingReservation->getNotes();
    $priceWelcomeDrink =        $bookingReservation->getPriceWelcomeDrink();
    $priceStarters =            $bookingReservation->getPriceStarters();
    $priceMainCourse =          $bookingReservation->getPriceMainCourse();
    $priceDessert =             $bookingReservation->getPriceDessert();
    $priceAccessories =         $bookingReservation->getPriceAccessories();
    $priceMidnightSnack =       $bookingReservation->getPriceMidnightSnack();
    $priceWine =                $bookingReservation->getPriceWine();
    $priceDessertWine =         $bookingReservation->getPriceDessertWine();
    $priceCognacAndLiqueur =    $bookingReservation->getPriceCognacAndLiqueur();
    $priceBar =                 $bookingReservation->getPriceBar();
    $priceBeerAndWater =        $bookingReservation->getPriceBeerAndWater();
    $priceCoffee =              $bookingReservation->getPriceCoffee();
    $priceTableArrangements =   $bookingReservation->getPriceTableArrangements();
    $priceTableClothsColor =    $bookingReservation->getPriceTableclothsColor();
    $priceCandleColor =         $bookingReservation->getPriceCandleColor();
    $priceTablePlan =           $bookingReservation->getPriceTablePlan();
    $priceNapkinColor =         $bookingReservation->getPriceNapkinColor();
    $priceFlowers =             $bookingReservation->getPriceFlowers();
    $priceMusicEntertainment =  $bookingReservation->getPriceMusicEntertainment();

    $query = "INSERT INTO " . DatabaseNames::$TABLE_BOOKING_RESERVATION;
    $query .= " VALUES( 'null',
                        '$date',
                        '$occasion',
                        '$guestId',
                        '$welcomeDrink',
                        '$starters',
                        '$mainCourse',
                        '$dessert',
                        '$accessories',
                        '$midnightSnack',
                        '$wine',
                        '$dessertWine',
                        '$cognacAndLiqueur',
                        '$bar',
                        '$beerAndWater',
                        '$coffee',
                        '$tableArrangements',
                        '$tableclothsColor',
                        '$candleColor',
                        '$tablePlan',
                        '$napkinColor',
                        '$flowers',
                        '$musicEntertainment',
                        '$notes',
                        '$priceWelcomeDrink',
                        '$priceStarters',
                        '$priceMainCourse',
                        '$priceDessert',
                        '$priceAccessories',
                        '$priceMidnightSnack',
                        '$priceWine',
                        '$priceDessertWine',
                        '$priceCognacAndLiqueur',
                        '$priceBar',
                        '$priceBeerAndWater',
                        '$priceCoffee',
                        '$priceTableArrangements',
                        '$priceTableClothsColor',
                        '$priceCandleColor',
                        '$priceTablePlan',
                        '$priceNapkinColor',
                        '$priceFlowers',
                        '$priceMusicEntertainment')";
    mysqli_query($this->con, $query);
```

Which is called by

```
    private function handleBaseBookingReservation($requestMethod) {
    switch ($requestMethod) {
        case 'POST':
            $date =                     $_POST['date'];
            $occasion =                 $_POST['occasion'];
            $guestId =                  $_POST['guestId'];
            $welcomeDrink =             $_POST['welcomeDrink'];
            $starters =                 $_POST['starters'];
            $mainCourse =               $_POST['mainCourse'];
            $dessert =                  $_POST['dessert'];
            $accessories =              $_POST['accessories'];
            $midnightSnack =            $_POST['midnightSnack'];
            $wine =                     $_POST['wine'];
            $dessertWine =              $_POST['dessertWine'];
            $cognacAndLiqueur =         $_POST['cognacAndLiqueur'];
            $bar =                      $_POST['bar'];
            $beerAndWater =             $_POST['beerAndWater'];
            $coffee =                   $_POST['coffee'];
            $tableArrangements =        $_POST['tableArrangements'];
            $tableclothsColor =         $_POST['tableclothsColor'];
            $candleColor =              $_POST['candleColor'];
            $tablePlan =                $_POST['tablePlan'];
            $napkinColor =              $_POST['napkinColor'];
            $flowers =                  $_POST['flowers'];
            $musicEntertainment =       $_POST['musicEntertainment'];
            $notes =                    $_POST['notes'];
            $priceWelcomeDrink =        $_POST['priceWelcomeDrink'];
            $priceStarters =            $_POST['priceStarters'];
            $priceMainCourse =          $_POST['priceMainCourse'];
            $priceDessert =             $_POST['priceDessert'];
            $priceAccessories =         $_POST['priceAccessories'];
            $priceMidnightSnack =       $_POST['priceMidnightSnack'];
            $priceWine =                $_POST['priceWine'];
            $priceDessertWine =         $_POST['priceDessertWine'];
            $priceCognacAndLiqueur =    $_POST['priceCognacAndLiqueur'];
            $priceBar =                 $_POST['priceBar'];
            $priceBeerAndWater =        $_POST['priceBeerAndWater'];
            $priceCoffee =              $_POST['priceCoffee'];
            $priceTableArrangements =   $_POST['priceTableArrangements'];
            $priceTableclothsColor =    $_POST['priceTableclothsColor'];
            $priceCandleColor =         $_POST['priceCandleColor'];
            $priceTablePlan =           $_POST['priceTablePlan'];
            $priceNapkinColor =         $_POST['priceNapkinColor'];
            $priceFlowers =             $_POST['priceFlowers'];
            $priceMusicEntertainment =  $_POST['priceMusicEntertainment'];

            // Guest ID, date and dateTime required
            if($guestId == null || $date == null) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request: Guest ID and date required');
            }

            $bookingReservation = new BookingReservation($date, $occasion, $guestId, $welcomeDrink, $starters, $mainCourse, $dessert,
                            $accessories, $midnightSnack, $wine, $dessertWine, $cognacAndLiqueur, $bar, $beerAndWater,
                            $coffee, $tableArrangements, $tableclothsColor, $candleColor, $tablePlan, $napkinColor,
                            $flowers, $musicEntertainment, $notes, $priceWelcomeDrink, $priceStarters, $priceMainCourse, $priceDessert,
                            $priceAccessories, $priceMidnightSnack, $priceWine, $priceDessertWine, $priceCognacAndLiqueur,
                            $priceBar, $priceBeerAndWater, $priceCoffee, $priceTableArrangements, $priceTableclothsColor,
                            $priceCandleColor, $priceTablePlan, $priceNapkinColor, $priceNapkinColor, $priceFlowers, $priceMusicEntertainment);

           $this->HCIModel->createBookingReservation($bookingReservation);
            break;
```

Also I know this is prone to SQL injections and all that good stuff, but this is for a university project, so I don't really care too much.

Comment: These strings at made dynamically, so I suppose that's not an option?

Comment: Your server request should make sure to specify the character encoding of the uploaded strings. Your server software must make sure to respect that encoding information when reading the data. The database that stores the string (if used here) must also support that encoding when writing to it and reading from it. You need to be more specific by showing some relevant minimal code snippets that reproduce the problem. Show the Android code that uploads the string, and the server code that processes the string.

Comment: I actually just tried setting this in a TextView dynamically from a String, and it worked just fine for me.  It seems like more of a server issue than an Android/Java issue.

Comment: yes more info is needed for diagnostics.

Comment: Most likely encoding.  Java strings by default are 16 bit unicode fixed width, the language was invented before UTF back when people still thought 2 byte character would solve everything.  When sending strings to/from a server you need to be careful of character encoding and encode in the correct format in and out.